# Nested function calls do not work after wrapping them with module.exports() in express.js

Tags: javascript

The nested functions calls do not work after putting all the functions inside the `module.exports()` like below. It used to work fine before exporting them.

First, `isValidCreds` is called, which calls `hasValidated`, which then calls `validateJWT`.

However, when I run the server I only get `"isValidCreds is called"`.
What is the problem?

```
module.exports = {
  isValidCreds: function (req, res, next) {
      console.log("isValidCreds is called");
        if(hasValidated(req)){
            next();
        }
        res.status(401);
        res.end("Unauthorized");
  },
  hasValidated: function (req) {
    console.log("hasValidated is called");
    var authz = req.headers["authorize"];
    if(typeof authz !== 'undefined'){
      var authzParts = authz.split(" ");
      if(authzParts[0] === "Bearer"){

        if( validateJWT(authzParts[1]) ){
          console.log("Authorized");
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  },
  validateJWT: function (jwtstring) {
    console.log("validateJWT is called");
    var jwtParts = jwtstring.split(".");
    var header = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtParts[0], 'base64').toString());
    var payload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtParts[1], 'base64').toString());
    var signature = jwtParts[2];

    var encodedHeader = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64');
    var encodedPayload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64');

    var username = payload.sub;
    currentUser = username;
    console.log("Verifying user:",username);

    var secret = secrets[username].secret;
    console.log("secret:",secret);
    var salt = payload.salt;
    secrets[username].salt = salt;

    var veriSign = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
      CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(
        CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedHeader + "." + encodedPayload,salt + secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
      )
    );
    veriSign = veriSign.replace('/','_');
    veriSign = veriSign.replace('+','-');
    return veriSign === signature;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no function or variable with the name `hasValidated` anymore, there it only an object that has the property `hasValidated` to which an anonymous function is assigned.

What you could do is to create regular function and export those. That way those functions don't depend on an object:

```
function isValidCreds(req, res, next) {
  console.log("isValidCreds is called");
  if (hasValidated(req)) {
    next();
  }
  res.status(401);
  res.end("Unauthorized");
}

function hasValidated(req) {
  console.log("hasValidated is called");
  var authz = req.headers["authorize"];
  if (typeof authz !== 'undefined') {
    var authzParts = authz.split(" ");
    if (authzParts[0] === "Bearer") {

      if (validateJWT(authzParts[1])) {
        console.log("Authorized");
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function validateJWT(jwtstring) {
  console.log("validateJWT is called");
  var jwtParts = jwtstring.split(".");
  var header = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtParts[0], 'base64').toString());
  var payload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtParts[1], 'base64').toString());
  var signature = jwtParts[2];

  var encodedHeader = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64');
  var encodedPayload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64');

  var username = payload.sub;
  currentUser = username;
  console.log("Verifying user:", username);

  var secret = secrets[username].secret;
  console.log("secret:", secret);
  var salt = payload.salt;
  secrets[username].salt = salt;

  var veriSign = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(
      CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedHeader + "." + encodedPayload, salt + secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
    )
  );
  veriSign = veriSign.replace('/', '_');
  veriSign = veriSign.replace('+', '-');
  return veriSign === signature;
}

module.exports = {
  isValidCreds,
  validateJWT,
  hasValidated
};
```

Or reference those functions using the `exports` object `exports.hasValidated`:

```js
module.exports = {
  isValidCreds: function (req, res, next) {
      console.log("isValidCreds is called");
        if(exports.hasValidated(req)){ // <===============
            next();
        }
        res.status(401);
        res.end("Unauthorized");
  },
  hasValidated: function (req) {
    console.log("hasValidated is called");
    var authz = req.headers["authorize"];
    if(typeof authz !== 'undefined'){
      var authzParts = authz.split(" ");
      if(authzParts[0] === "Bearer"){

        if( exports.validateJWT(authzParts[1]) ){ // <===============
          console.log("Authorized");
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  },
  validateJWT: function (jwtstring) {
    console.log("validateJWT is called");
    var jwtParts = jwtstring.split(".");
    var header = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtParts[0], 'base64').toString());
    var payload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtParts[1], 'base64').toString());
    var signature = jwtParts[2];

    var encodedHeader = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64');
    var encodedPayload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64');

    var username = payload.sub;
    currentUser = username;
    console.log("Verifying user:",username);

    var secret = secrets[username].secret;
    console.log("secret:",secret);
    var salt = payload.salt;
    secrets[username].salt = salt;

    var veriSign = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
      CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(
        CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedHeader + "." + encodedPayload,salt + secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
      )
    );
    veriSign = veriSign.replace('/','_');
    veriSign = veriSign.replace('+','-');
    return veriSign === signature;
  }
};
```

`this.hasValidated` would also work, but is a bad idea, because it is not obvious to the reader that the functions exported by the module depend would need to be called on the `exports` of that module.

So something like:

```js
let {isValidCreds} = require('your module')

//....

app.use(isValidCreds)
```

would fail if you use `this.hasValidated`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `this.methodName`

```
var test = {
   prop: 42,
   func: function() {
     return this.prop;
   },
};

// expected output: 42
console.log(test.func());
```

Comment: it's just node js with express

Comment: `isValidCreds: function (req, res, next) ` indicates that `isValidCreds` is used as middleware (`app.use(isValidCreds)`)  so `this` could referencfe some other object in that case.

Comment: It's interesting, I didn't know. Thanks